# Backend user creation form with additional language field

Tags: user-registration

I need to create users in the backend which currently works. After adding the user, he gets an email currently in english. I want to make this dynamically to the given language in the backend user creation form.

Currently there is no option to directly pass a specific language or parameter while creating the user in the backend.

How can I basically add an additional field to the user creation form, so that I can check wether the email shall be sent out in english or any other language.

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246458) - it can help you add the additional profile field.